# ¿Cómo obtengo una vista por usuario?

Tags: laravel-5

Quiero que en el index, un usuario únicamente pueda ver lo que el guarda en una tabla, alguien me podría ayudar. Gracias

De momento tengo mi consulta de esta manera:

```
public function index()
     {
          $depositos=Deposito::table('depositos')
                               ->where( 'id_usuario','=', Auth::id())
                               ->get();

          return view('depositos.index');
     }
```

Y me genera este error: `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::table()`

Comment: Hola user66297, bienvenido al sitio!, te invito a realizar el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento básico del sitio. Para que obtengas buenas respuestas te sugiero leer [ask], tu pregunta debe ser modificada ya que fue reportada como de baja calidad, es importante revisar [ask] saludos!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que te está diciendo el mensaje es que `table` no es un método definido en `Deposito`.

Si tienes montadas las relaciones en el modelo `Usuarios` con el modelo `Depositos` de la siguiente forma:

```
public function depositos()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Depositos', 'id_usuario');
    }
```

Será muy sencillo encontrar todos los depósitos de ese usuario:

```
$depositos=Auth::user()->depositos;
```